# Causative meanings of transitive and intransitive verbs

Tags: verbs, causatives

I was reading "The Language Instinct" by Steven Pinker, and he says in the book that certain verbs (like play and cook) don't undergo a certain causative rule. You can read the portion here at [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Language_Instinct/UtFqXQosVP0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E2%80%9CThe+causative+rule+can+apply+to+some+verbs+but+not+others%22&pg=PT280&printsec=frontcover).

> The butter melted → Sally melted the butter

This is one of the example he gives. Why can't we use "cook" and "play" this way? Here are some examples I made up:

> John played → John played football.

> John cooked → John cooked a meal.

> *The meat cooked → John cooked the meat. ("The meat cooked" example doesn't feel right)

Was he referring to sentences just like my last example? If yes what's the difference between the transitive and intransitive meanings in my first two examples and the last example?

I can see that the verb in my last example doesn't have a similar role like the melted in "the butter melted" example. Is that the difference Pinker is referring to here?

Comment: In some contexts, "The meat cooked" is a valid sentence/phrase. For example, "The meat cooked in the pan while I tended to the rice" sounds natural to me.

Comment: Your Google Books search won't let me look at the previous page, but another search shows that the 'causative rule' seems to refer to constructions like _have something done_ or _get something done_. I don't see how Sally and the butter apply to this! You can have a meal cooked for you, or (stretching a point) have a tune played.

Comment: @KateBunting I think you can see the previous page if you scroll down to the next page and scroll back to the previous page (some kinda bug I guess, but it seems to work for me).

Comment: @Griffin "Verbs involving fully voluntary actions, like cook and play, refuse to undergo the rule in almost every language." This is what he has written. I am not a native speaker myself so I am not sure if your example is natural for a native reader.

Comment: Thanks - it worked for me too, but I still don't understand his reasoning.  _The meat cooked_ is a valid expression (it became so hot that it underwent a change).

Comment: @KateBunting Would you also agree that "the music played" is in the same form?

Comment: @PrimeMover - Yes, I think it is.

Comment: I think the author is making inferences where none exist. *The meat cooked* does not mean that anyone is actively cooking it. To miss this when you are writing a book about grammar doesn’t reflect well in the author.

Comment: The link you give says there's no preview available. Can you edit the question and add the relevant portions from the book?